# Strange error 403: Acces Forbidden in Sharepoint 2013 IIS

Tags: sharepoint, iis

For the first time, I' m facing  an unusual error when I 'm trying to access to a site collection in SharePoint 2013, just created. Error 403 + access denied concerning ISAPI module?

I retrieve the error in the `IIS log -> Warning`:

```
-MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName   IsapiModule 
Notification  128 
HttpStatus 403 
HttpReason FORBIDDEN 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode L’opération a réussi. (0x0)
```

`Infrormations:`

All site collections in the Web app have the issue. I check the rights on directories,  it's okay.

```
Authentification : Anonymous Authentification    Enabled
                      ASP.Net Impersonation         Enabled
                      Basic Authentification        Disabled
                      Digest Authentification       Disabled
                      Forms  Authentification       Enabled
                      Windows Authentification      Enabled
```

Is it a problem into IIS?

Into  Handler mapping   /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll   have acces SCRIPT

Thanks for your help, Christophe.

---

everything seems correct on the side of access rights to files, and authorization by the side of CGI scripts

I incline rather to conflict linked to a previous installation of Office 
Microsoft Office Live Add-in 1.3? or a missing dll? the side 
ASP. NET?

Have you an idea of it?

---

More informations about my configuration on IIS:

1) ISAPI and CGI restrictions Allowed for all dll paths

2) Handler mapping Permissions : read , script and execute for feature OwssvrHandler

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\isapi\owssvr.dll

3) Permissions acces "all rights" for everybody on foldes C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15

and C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80

Is this a problem due to the fact that Sharepoint 2010 has already been installed on the machine?

Best regards

Comment: I'm worried you delved right into the IIS logs. What do the SharePoint ULS logs say? Does the request even get passed to SP? Try expanding your web application to a fresh one with a different URL. Any errors in the event log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to allow all on iis/ISAPI and CGI (to avoid message access denied concerning ISAPI module)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar error, this was my salvation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942065